# XFS Quota - Cannot exceed soft limit but hard limit and grace period are OK

Tags: quota, xfs

I am using Centos-7 with a local XFS file system and I am having this problem implementing quotas. It is all set up and everything looks correct. I can change limits, grace period, check the quotas and it all looks good. However, when I create files that exceed the soft limit, the system then prevents me creating any more files even though I haven't reach the hard limit or grace period. I have tried changing the hard limit, even to 0, and grace period, but there is no difference.

Anybody seen this issue?

> quota -v -f /home
> Disk quotas for user antony (uid 1000):
> Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
> /dev/mapper/cl-home
> 79246016  80987136       0         1265627       0       0

## Quota looks OK

## Now create a few big dummy files

> dd if=/dev/zero of=~/fred1 bs=128M count=8
> Warning: user antony block quota exceeded.
> 8+0 records in
> 8+0 records out
> 1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 1.72881 s, 621 MB/s

> dd if=/dev/zero of=~/fred2 bs=128M count=8
> Warning: user antony block quota exceeded.
> Warning: user antony block quota exceeded.
> 8+0 records in
> 8+0 records out
> 1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 1.6973 s, 633 MB/s

> dd if=/dev/zero of=~/fred3 bs=128M count=8
> Warning: user antony block quota exceeded.
> Warning: user antony block quota exceeded.
> Warning: user antony block quota exceeded.
> Warning: user antony block quota exceeded.
> dd: error writing '/home/antony/fred3': Disk quota exceeded
> 1+0 records in
> 0+0 records out
> 4194304 bytes (4.2 MB, 4.0 MiB) copied, 0.1746 s, 24.0 MB/s
> Info: user antony block quota exceeded too long.
> Info: user antony block quota exceeded too long.
> Info: user antony block quota exceeded too long.
> Info: user antony block quota exceeded too long.
> Info: user antony block quota exceeded too long.
> Info: user antony block quota exceeded too long.

> ls -l ~/fred*
> -rw-rw-r--. 1 antony antony 1073741824 Jan 19 12:08 /home/antony/fred1
> -rw-rw-r--. 1 antony antony 1073741824 Jan 19 12:08 /home/antony/fred2
> -rw-rw-r--. 1 antony antony    4194304 Jan 19 12:08 /home/antony/fred3

## fred3 did not get created properly

> quota -v
> Disk quotas for user antony (uid 1000):
> Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
> /dev/mapper/cl-root
> 26244       0       0              36       0       0
> /dev/mapper/cl-home
> 81347264* 80987136       0   6days 1265630       0       0

## Soft limit exceeded. No hard limit. Grace period OK.